# Can I set image aspect ratio when scaling in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I haven't found a way to scale based on aspect ratio:

[image]
Scaling with [`keep aspect`](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-scale.html) option (chain icon) disabled can be used when fixing images stretched from 4:3 to a widescreen resolution, for example.
I can set resolution for my aspect ratio manually, but that of course isn't optimal.

Comment: What abut this: Unselect the "chain". If your aspect ratio is X:Y, set the width to X and the height to Y. Now, turn the chain on again, change the Width and the height will be recomputed (to satisfy your ratio).

Comment: You mean in width/height or X/Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (simple) mathematical expressions in the entry fields. For instance to resize your image to 4:3, keep the height (1080) and in the width field enter `1080*4/3`.

Comment: I can't get the method to work: https://i.imgur.com/hzk5XY9.png - the image is scaled to 810 x 1080, 3:4 aspect ratio.

Comment: Sorry got it backwards, I meant width to `1080x4/3` (if you want to keep the height) or height to 1920*3/4 (if you want to keep the width).

Comment: You can answer this question as well, I inadvertently "cross-posted": https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90032/how-to-scale-image-aspect-ratio-in-gimp

Answer (score 1):

The aspect ratio is not a unit of sizes like pixel or inches, but the relation between the width and height.

To scale while keeping the aspect ratio, simply click on the chain and rescale by dragging on the layer or enter either width or height, the other dimension will change automatically to keep the original aspect ratio.

To make a layer a certain aspect ratio, simply keep the chain unattached and enter the aspect ratio for the width and height (ie Width 4 Height 3 for 4:3). Then click on the chain and scale to the size you need.